# will a "ab3p7000ba" transmission be compatible for a 2015 ford ranger px1 2015 "ab3p7000bc"?

Tags: ford, transmission, ranger, 4wd, compatibility

I have a 2015 ford ranger auto px1 4wd 3.2L needing a new transmission. I have found one but the part number is 1 letter different. my part number is  "ab3p7000bc"and the part I found is  "ab3p7000ba". will this be compatible? thank you

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!